# Spring Boot JWT authorization throws 401 even with a valid token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, swagger-ui, bearer-token

Below is my web security config class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "authority")
@Profile({"cloud", "development", "release"})
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private Map<String, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private List<String> whiteList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/students").authenticated()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/students/*").authenticated()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/students/*").access("hasRole('learning_management_admin_app1000000')")
                      .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/students").access("hasRole('learning_management_admin_app1000000')");


        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(getWhiteList().toArray(new String[0]))
                .permitAll();

        http.cors();
        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
    }

    public List<String> getWhiteList() {
       ..
```

And In the controller,

```
@Validated
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "BearerAuth")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public class StudentsController {

 @GetMapping("change-requests")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('learning_management_admin_app1000000')")
 public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getStudents(
            @RequestParam(required = false) String name) {
```

Here even with a valid token, it throws 401 Unauthorized exception from every endpoint. Even in the swagger ui, it throws 401 unauthorized with a valid token.

Comment: Token could be valid but missing the required claims (i.e. authorizations) to what resources it can access , agree?

Comment: Activate `debug` or `trace` logging to see what happens, should help to find the cause

Comment: Does the curl command shown in Swagger UI when you do "try it out" include the auth token?

Comment: @Helen Yes it does have the bearer taken passing